# Setting Cookie before loading a page in FMX.TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

I need to set some Cookies in a `FMX.TWebBrowser` before navigating to the destination URL in a **Firemonkey C++/Delphi** application. In VCL we could query the `TWebBrowser.Document` for `IHTMLDocument2` and get access to the cookies from there. But in FMX version, I cannot find and reference to the Document or Cookies. Also is it possible to manipulate the ***User Agent String***? I am using *RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin*. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
P. S. I can use both C++ and Delphi.
Thank you
Sam